# Get All Rows From a Postgres Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

We have a table in a Postgres DB that lists, among other things, two integers, say i1, i2 and a double, say d.

For some reason, we need all values of these fields in all rows in this table. Also, we need to do this using Java, don't ask me why.

I'm trying to see the most efficient way of doing this. Of course I can Execute a Java Statement with a query

```
SELECT i1, i2, d FROM mytable;
```

and then iterate over ResultSet. I'm concerned that this might burden the DB.

The Table likely contains several million rows (definitely less than 10m) and we're only interested in these three fields.

If there was a single column primary Key, I can easily write a cursored call, like so

```
SELECT i1, i2, d FROM mytable where primarykey > ?;
```

But the table does not have a single column primary key.

While i1 and i2 are guaranteed to be unique, table does not have an index, and given that this is only a one time activity, it is unlikely anyone in team would be interested in creating one.

Without index, I suspect selecting all rows is actually going to be cheaper than ordering by i1, and i2 and then writing a cursored call using these.

What is the most efficient and least problematic way of doing this?

Comment: The select statement you have show is the only way to do that. However you probably want to configure the driver to fetch the results using a cursor: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: you can "prepare" data by creating an index on those 3 fields - this way select will scan only index, but it only makes sence if you often scan those 3 columns only and additional index is affordable

Comment: Hi, there is no single column primary Key and while i1 and i2 are guaranteed to be unique, there is no index. Updated the post with this description. Sorry to have forgotten that while writing original description.

Comment: Have you tried `(i1, i2) > (?, ?)`? And as _a horse_ says: you can also fetch using a cursor (I believe PostgreSQL defaults to fetching all).

Comment: Hi Mark, Thats possible, but might be costlier without index than a blind select.

Comment: Hi  a_horse_with_no_name, I was pretty sure the Postgres driver does not actually get all rows at once, but fetches them from DB as and when needed for a "select *", but I wanted to be absolutely sure considering this is a Prod DB. Link you posted says definitively that this is the case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the select to get all rows. Postgres can absolutely handle that.

Leave out any `order by` to make processing less expensive.

The only concern you should have is the memory consumption of the driver. By default the Postgres driver buffers **all** rows in memory before returning from an `executeQuery()` call.

You probably need to configure the driver to not do that. This is covered in the driver's manual:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: Quick follow up question - does this work with PreparedStatement? i.e. will this limit the fetch size of a PreparedStatement Query?

Comment: @D159 It will work with a `PreparedStatement` as well (wouldn't make much sense if it didn't)